# SQL Database Query: Count(Distinct)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I am working on an SQL query to do the following:

> For each project on which more than two employees work, retrieve the  project number, the project name, and the number of employees who work  on that project.

This is what I have currently for project number 1:

```
SELECT project.PNO, project.PNAME, COUNT(DISTINCT works_on.ESSN)
AS '# of employess worked on'

FROM project INNER JOIN works_on
ON project.PNO = works_on.PNO

INNER JOIN employee
ON works_on.ESSN = employee.SSN

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT works_on.ESSN) > 2
AND project.PNO LIKE 1
```

and it returns:

PNO:1

PNAME:ProductX

number of employess worked on: 7

When it should return NULL since project number 1 only has two distinct ESSNs in the works_on table, but instead it is returning the total number of distinct ESSNs in the works_on table

Attached is my schema:

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: You forgot to `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have there results by project, meaning you're missing a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT     project.PNO,
           project.PNAME, 
           COUNT(DISTINCT works_on.ESSN) AS '# of employess worked on'
FROM       project 
INNER JOIN works_on ON project.PNO = works_on.PNO
INNER JOIN employee ON works_on.ESSN = employee.SSN
GROUP BY   project.PNO, project.PNAME -- Here!
HAVING     COUNT(DISTINCT works_on.ESSN) > 2 AND project.PNO LIKE 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pal! I understand how to use GROUP BY for ordering data in the results, but can you explain how using it here helped?

Comment: @jaxicab `group by` isn't for ordering - that's the `order by` clause. `group by` makes the database return a single row (with it's aggregate functions) per distinct value you are grouping here. Here, we use it to apply the `count` per project instead of on the entire dataset.

Comment: Makes sense, this was a big help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Group by and the where clause like this:

```
SELECT project.PNO, project.PNAME, COUNT(DISTINCT works_on.ESSN)
AS '# of employess worked on'

FROM project INNER JOIN works_on
ON project.PNO = works_on.PNO

INNER JOIN employee
ON works_on.ESSN = employee.SSN
where project.PNO LIKE 1
group by project.PNO, project.PNAME 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT works_on.ESSN) > 2
```